# Advanced Search algorithm on Google Appengine datastore and indexes

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, jinja2, google-app-engine-python

I am using appengine with python (version 2.7) for a web application which deals with job listings and job search. 
Backend consists of a "Job" table which consists of 20+ fields such as title,date,experience etc. I have the necessary composite indexes defined for each of the filter's permutation and combination. As you would have guessed, the number of indexes are high.

The front-end provides option for users to search for jobs and filter them using the columns.

This works as expected but with following drawbacks:

- Slow Search Performance
- The search is divided into two parts: inbuilt datastore filtering and then a custom filtering on top of the refined results. The custom filtering is required to further apply the complex filters which are not supported by appengine.
- Exploding composite indexes

Some columns (5 for instance) accepts only a set of values, so filtering using them is pretty straightforward. While other fields can have user defined values and hence filtering through them requires custom python code.

Jinja is the templating engine which then renders the data into the html.

Advanced Search + Index References: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection

Is there a better approach/algorithm for implementing the search and advanced search in the appengine?

Comment: Though there's already a valid answer posted here, I would nonetheless recommend posting this more general question on the [App Engine Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-appengine) as it is somewhat broad for an SO question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to consider using the [Full Text Search](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/search/) API available in App Engine. In essence, when entities are created in Cloud Datastore, you would create a Document with the entity ID/Key and all searchable fields and send it to the Search API for indexing. Any updates to the Datastore entities would also need to update the corresponding Search document. Also, when entities are deleted, delete the corresponding Search document.

Modify your Application's search code to perform the Search on Indexed documents instead of Datastore queries. Retrieve a page (e.g. 50) of Document IDs. Fetch the data for the 50 entities using a Datastore Get and display the results.

Per the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/) -

> The Search API lets your application perform Google-like full-text
>   searches over structured data, and supports Geolocation-based queries.
>   It can be useful in any application domain that benefits from
>   full-text search, such as:

This would definitely give a better Search experience for your application users when compared with Datastore queries.

Once you implement this, you *might* be able to just get rid of the composite indexes from Datastore.

Comment: The search API too has some limitations on the search operators. There are certain operators which are not supported.

Comment: @KK Which unsupported operators do you need?  Can you describe the specific search you're looking to accomplish in your question?  Otherwise, this answer should suffice.